# error while Using malloc in creating 2D and 1D array

Tags: c, arrays, matrix, malloc

I am creating 1d arrays B and T of n size and a 2D array A of nxn size,where n has been computed earlier.
But the program crashes after Pause, what am i possibly doing wrong??

```
float *B = malloc(sizeof(int) * (n));
float *T = malloc(sizeof(int) * (n));
system("PAUSE");
float **A;                                                    
A = malloc(sizeof(int) * (n));
for(j = 0; j < n; j++)
{ 
    A[j] = malloc(sizeof(int) * (j));
}
```

i, j and n are integers.

Comment: `sizeof(int)` isn't good here, it should be `sizeof(float)` and `sizeof(float*)` for `A`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never repeat the type name in the argument to `malloc()`; doing so makes it easy to say the wrong type, which creates errors.

You should use `sizeof`, like so:

```
float *B = malloc(n * sizeof *B);
float **A = malloc(n * sizeof *A);
for(j = 0; j < n; ++j)
  A[j] = malloc(n * sizeof *A[j]);
```

Also, in C [you shouldn't  cast the return value of `malloc()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/28169).

Answer (score 3):

> a 2D array A of nxn size

You're passing the wrong types to `sizeof`. You should be using `sizeof(float)` and `sizeof(float *)`. But the more serious (and insidious) problem is:

```
A[j]=(float*)malloc(sizeof(int)*(j));
                                 ^
```

You want `n` instead of `j`.

Comment: Even more serious problem: casting the return value of `malloc()` in C.

Comment: But how does allocating a triangular shape cause a crash?

Comment: @BoPersson The OP said "a 2D array A of nxn size". So presumably that's how it's being used.